# Looking for a basic and up-to-date Cassandra tutorial

Tags: cassandra

I would like to learn Cassandra.

Unfortunately, the few tutorial posts I could find either refer to an old Cassandra version (prior 1) and/or require a somewhat complicated setup, like installing twissandra.

So, I wonder if anyone knows a resource to learn Cassandra without having to install anything, except Cassandra itself, of course.

My setup:

- Windows 7 (should not matter, right?)
- Cassandra 1.2.0 (installed using the binary installer from DataStax)
- OpsCenter (courtesy of DataStax)

I am pretty comfortable with MongoDB and have some experience with MySql, though it seems that Cassandra is like none of the above.

Anyone?

Comment: don't know a ressource sorry, but if you only want to use it as a db it seems that it can be requested like any sql based db: http://aquiles.codeplex.com/

Comment: I want to learn its potential. Using it as an sql based db does not seem to advance me in the right direction.

Comment: if you want to know its potential, then yep, irrelevant sorry

Answer (score 9):

I recommend the video tutorials

http://www.devoxx.com/display/Devoxx2K10/Cassandra+by+Example

and some presentations by datastax

http://www.datastax.com/company/news-and-events/events/cassandrasf2011/presentations

I recommend the below link also which i feel that it has all basic database administration topics which you may be interested to learn with latest version...

Try this tutorial https://www.i2tutorials.com/cassandra-tutorial/

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/index.htm

Comment: https://academy.datastax.com/

Comment: link http://www.devoxx.com/display/Devoxx2K10/Cassandra+by+Example is dead

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this probably depends on what you want to do. Like any database technology, Cassandra has a lot of facets. I would say these fall into a few categories:

1. Overview of features and functions
2. Installation
3. Reading & writing data
4. Operations
5. Schema design

DataStax has done a very good job creating documentation on the first 4 points, so if that's your concern I'd suggest reading through their docs.  Also, you'll want to review the docs for the specific client library you plan to use.

Schema design is a bit trickier, as good rules and design patterns are being discovered all the time.  There are some well-traveled paths in this area, but to a large degree this is something you learn through experience and asking specific questions in places like this or the Cassandra IRC channel.

If you're having trouble with some specific aspect of your own mental Cassandra bootstrapping process, I would suggest asking a specific question.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking the right question often implies knowing 50% of the answer :-). I just want a tutorial, which takes from zero up to some point where one can start doing meaningful things. I read the documentation, but it is not the same.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but surely you have done something other than just install it.  Have you tried acquiring a client library?  Creating some column families and writing to them?  If I wrote a question on SO saying "I want to learn MySQL", people would want to know what I'm trying to do.  You either have some problem you're trying to solve that has you looking at solutions, or you're kicking the tires.  If the former, fill us in on that.  If the latter, what's blocking you from just playing around?

Comment: It is the latter. I want to limit my choice points. For instance, when I learned mongo I used extensively their command line shell coupled with the simple examples in their documentation. Thus I avoided the need to chose between the different existing client side libraries (should I pick that Java implementation vs that .NET implementation vs that node.js implementation? and what if that one is not suitable for a beginner, etc...) Cassandra has a command line shell, so this is only natural to assume it should be enough to get started. But where are the basic tutorials?

Comment: Cassandra has two shells available, `cassandra-cli` and `cqlsh`.  The former is more rudimentary and suitable for dealing with raw storage rows.  The latter is higher level and provides a shell for executing CQL commands.  I'm a bit old school and prefer the CLI, since I do not use CQL, but `cqlsh` is what DataStax is pushing people toward.  For a CQL reference, [check this out](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/index).

Comment: It's also worth noting that Cassandra is a more complex database than Mongo, and as a result it's less easily distilled into a simple tutorial.

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/rastrick/presentation-12982302) might also help.  It's for 1.1 and doesn't include CQL, but it will give you a good foundation, and the code is on github.

Comment: [Here](http://www.planetcassandra.org/Learn/CassandraCommunityWebinars) is one more site where you can find some good webinars that might help.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you the book "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide" by Eben Hewitt
[http://www.amazon.com/Cassandra-Definitive-Guide-Eben-Hewitt/dp/1449390412](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449390412)

It contains the basics for the database and also for no-SQL modeling.

I also found this resource quite useful while understanding Cassandra configuration parameters: http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

Of course, you won't be able to survive without http://www.datastax.com/docs

Comment: This book was written against 0.7 which is far out of date to the point of almost being irrelevant.  For one thing since wanting information on cassandra 1.2+ will probably want CQL not thrift based examples.  Thrift still and will probably always work but 0.7 will be missing a ton of things also (ie leveled compaction).

Comment: I agree with you but so far I couldn't find any updated documentation.  Anyway, I still recommend this book for beginners; and after that, datastax.